# Get dimensions of raster without reading it to memory

Tags: python, raster, rasterio, numpy

I have an URL to a TIFF file:

```
url = "https://copernicus-dem-30m.s3.amazonaws.com/Copernicus_DSM_COG_10_N59_00_E010_00_DEM/Copernicus_DSM_COG_10_N59_00_E010_00_DEM.tif"
```

I can get the dimensions of this file via:

```
src = rasterio.open(url)
r = src.read(1)
r.shape
```

which returns `(3600, 2400)`.

**Is there a way or getting these two numbers without the `src.read(1)` line?**

It seems like a waste to read all the raster in if I only want to get the dimensions of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to read the file in:

```py
import rasterio as rio
# Remote file as an example:
url="/vsicurl/https://copernicus-dem-30m.s3.amazonaws.com/Copernicus_DSM_COG_10_N59_00_E010_00_DEM/Copernicus_DSM_COG_10_N59_00_E010_00_DEM.tif"
s=rio.open(url)
print(s.width, s.height)
```

or using the plain GDAL bindings:

```py
from osgeo import gdal 
url="/vsicurl/https://copernicus-dem-30m.s3.amazonaws.com/Copernicus_DSM_COG_10_N59_00_E010_00_DEM/Copernicus_DSM_COG_10_N59_00_E010_00_DEM.tif"
g = gdal.OpenEx(url)
print(g.RasterXSize, g.RasterYSize)
```

Both of these incantations will return 2400 x 3600 (not difference in order to numpy array).

Answer (score 5):

```
import rasterio
src = rasterio.open(url)
print(src.height)
3600
print(src.width)
2400
```